# Nestjs typeorm inject repository best practices

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using Typeorm & nestjs.

I have question about injecting repository in service.

Usually, sample codes lead me to write below when inject repository in service

```
export class AService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository() aRepo: ARepo
    ) {}
}
```

This always has to write TypeOrm.feature([ARepo]) in AModule

```
imports: [TypeOrm.feature([ARepo])
```

But if I write code below

```
export class AService {
    this.aRepo: ARepo;
    constructor(
        @InjectConnection() connection: Connection
    ){
        this.aRepo = this.connection.getCustomRepository(ARepo);
    }
}
```

I don't have to connect any repository in Module.

Why we use first way?

Comment: The first way uses dependency injection which is in general a better practice than the second example. It is also much cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: I'm really curious about Di on second way. I also think that first way obviously use DI, so nestjs can handle repository. But what about second way? is it just make another instance everytime?

Comment: The second approach does use DI for the connection object but not for the repository. I'm not sure if a new instance is created every time you call the `getCustomRepository` method.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this comes down to your own preference.  From what I can see in the GitHub repo for Nest TypeOrm, `forFeature` is just delegating to `getCustomRepository` anyways, so there isn't any functional difference there.

However, there are some important benefits (IMO) to the first way that you don't get with the second way.

First, when it comes time to test your services, you only need to mock your repositories.  With the second way, you'd need to mock the repositories in addition to the connection, creating more work for yourself and a larger surface area to test.

IMO, in the absence of any performance or other gains, this is reason enough to stick to the first method.

Second, it's much more expected and much clearer to explicitly define your models in the `forRoot`.  Other developers can reference your module to see what it's responsible for without needing to dive into your services.

Lastly, I should point out that while the second method is technically using dependency injection, it's not using dependency injection for the model itself, which you're presumably importing at the top of your file.  This pattern is potentially limiting, as it becomes much harder to mock that imported repo if you ever need to in the future.

TLDR: If you don't care about any of the benefits, or are able to work around them, then there's functionally no difference between the two.  They both do the same thing, and internally Nest calls the same methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just got kind of annoying that I have to DI Connection if i need to transaction, so I found second solution. And I already mocked Connection object globally, so I didn't care about test in this case. But I agree with your second and third reason. Thanks for your insights!